# Update mysql table coloumn value based on decimal and length

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a column(varchar) with values like 
`220330`
`100300`
`94300`
Now I need to update these values based on the following two condition

- put decimal before last two digit
- if count is not equal to 6 then make it by concatenating 0 ahead.

So now values be like `2203.30` `1003.00` `0943.00`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Which is your data field type?

Comment: column data type is varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
update your_table
set col = concat (
        lpad(substring(col, 1, char_length(col) - 2), 4, '0'),
        '.',
        lpad(right(col, 2), 2, '0')
        );
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/JSBJU8009)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
select lpad(format(val / 100, 2), 6, '0')
```

Comment: Thnks for reply but your method does not concatenate '0' if length is less than 6 also in many cases it is omitting ".00"